# Ошибка при установке geopandas

Tags: python

Не получается установить библиотеку geopandas.
Пробовал установить дистрибутивы с этого сайта [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)
Именно после установки файлов с этого сайта стало выдавать то, что показано на 1 скрине, но библиотека все равно не работает!
При установке в виртуальной среде выдает такую ошибку (3 скрин)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы используете виртуальное окружение?

Comment: да, использую..

Comment: Не забыли активировать окружение перед тем как устанавливать библиотеку?

Comment: нет, не забыл..

Comment: В конце ошибки есть и путь решения — Вам нужно установить Microsoft C++ Build Tools. Кстати, эта проблема описана в [документации](https://geopandas.org/getting_started/install.html#installing-with-pip). Советовал бы ставить через `conda`.

Comment: спасибо!!!.....